# INSERT row with known variables AND SELECT'ed value (VB)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I need to insert a new row, which includes both known variables from VB.net AND data from another table - I'm working in ASP.NET VB, and SAL server 2008.

This is what i have: (edited to be more readable)

```
sql = "INSERT INTO [TABLE]([column1],[column2],[column3]) 
values('" + variable1 + "','" + variable2 + "','(SELECT [SOMETHING] FROM [TABLE2] WHERE [RowID] = " + Variable3 + ")')"
```

The statement executes and works, but the column that i want to populate with the SELECT statement is empty.

I assume its a syntax thing but i cant figure it out...

Comment: What happens when you do a sql.ToString()?

Comment: all variables are properly populated into the string

Comment: This works for me.  Im guessing this is an example and not the real data you are inserting.  Could the real data be causing the problem?

Comment: ok, i have figured this out.... annoyingly it was my fault, I had forgotten to comment out a line below that over-wrote the SQL string!!!! - bugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably your SELECT statement shouldn't have single quotes around it.

```
values('" + variable1 + "','" + variable2 + "','(SELECT [SOMETHING] FROM [TABLE2] WHERE [RowID] = " + Variable3 + ")')"
```

Should read

```
values('" + variable1 + "','" + variable2 + "',(SELECT [SOMETHING] FROM [TABLE2] WHERE [RowID] = " + Variable3 + "))"
```

You should consider using String.Format, it makes this much more readable:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format-vbnet

```
Dim var1 as String = "Bar"
Dim var2 as String = "Foo"
Dim Var3 as Integer = 1
Dim subquery as String = String.Format("(SELECT [SOMETHING] FROM [TABLE2] WHERE [RowID] = {0} )", var3)
Dim sql As String = String.Format("INSERT INTO [TABLE]([column1],[column2],[column3]) values('{0}', '{1}', {2})", var1, var2, subquery)
```

Comment: It makes it more reabable, but does it have any effect on the final string? in my original there is no " around the select statement in the final sql string.

Comment: No effect on the final string. ==>'(SELECT  and ")')"

Comment: there is no " in the output string?